# Data Frame Column Name Text Color and Index Text Color Changing Problem in Streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, ag-grid, streamlit, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to change the data frame row (index) and column name text color? Additionally, how do I change the width of the data frame?

```
df_count=df["ACIKLAMA"].value_counts(ascending=False).to_frame()
    df_count.columns=["count_of_purchase/campaign"]
    max_purchasing=df_count.iloc[0:1]
    max_purchasing.rename(columns = {'count_of_purchase/campaign':'max_count_of_purchase/campaign'}, inplace = True)
    #print("max number of purchasing/campaign frequency:\n\n",max_purchasing)
    
    
    
# only valid for cell values
 st.markdown('<style>div[class="css-o1jpvw e19lei0e1"] { color: black; background:white;font-weight: normal; } .data:hover{ background:cyan;)}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True) 


# this is not working
 st.dataframe(max_purchasing,height=1000,width=390)
```

[image]

**with AgGrid (left text missing):**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the streamlit **AgGrid Component** which is installed as `pip install streamlit-aggrid`. But of course you will have to write some **css** to style your dataframe.

With `st.dataframe(max_purchasing,height=1000,width=390)`, it doesn't really give you the best output but **AgGrid** can handle this simply problem. All you need is `AgGrid(max_purchasing)` after installing the module and importing it as `from st_aggrid import AgGrid`, you can feather adjust the size of the dataframe to your liking.

You can refer to ***[AgGrid Doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation-colours/)*** for more information on how to style your dataframe to your liking.

But remember, if you want to use **AgGrid** in streamlit, you might want to also refer to the ***[streamlit-aggrid component](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components)*** to have an idea on how the module is implemented in streamlit.

Comment: AgGrid(max_purchasing,height=200,width=1200,theme="streamlit",allow_unsafe_jscode="True",fit_columns_on_grid_load=True) I tried this code but the text which is the left (TRENDYOL.COM) does not seem on the dataframe.

Comment: Imagine, you are having `width=1200` that is exactly what is hiding some of your data. Reduce `width=1200` and remove or set to `fit_columns_on_grid_load=False` because that take the default width of the amount of data you  have.

Comment: I did the mentioned things, but resut is still same.

Comment: Try not setting `width` and `height` to see if that works.

Comment: I tried without width and height, same.